# jQuery targeting aria attribute containing value

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an HTML structure of :

```
<div class="someclass" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="my-specified-action my-one-name">
<div class="someclass" tabindex="1" aria-describedby="my-specified-action my-two-name">
<div class="someclass" tabindex="2" aria-describedby="my-specified-action my-three-name">
<div class="someclass" tabindex="3" aria-describedby="my-specified-action my-four-name">
<div class="someclass" tabindex="3" aria-describedby="my-specified-action my-five-name">
```

I need to hide all elements that has an attribute `aria-describedby` containing my value ( for example `four` ), but leave all others untouched.

```
jQuery('div[aria-describedby*="four"]').hide()
```

of course, if I will do :

```
jQuery('div:not([aria-describedby*="four"])').hide()
```

it will hide ALL elements ( also the ones containing my target ..)

for some reason, this is not working for me ,..

```
jQuery('div:not([aria-describedby^="four"])').hide()
```

what am I doing wrong ??

Comment: because there is no attribute value starting with `four`

Comment: your second code is fine does not hide all elements - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4cdak/1/

Comment: first one also is fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4cdak/2/

Comment: isnt´s the `*` stands for `containing` ? ( sorry, I am really bad with anything that is not PHP )

Comment: yes... so if the attribute value contains four it will match the selector - so it hides the element with attribute value `my-specified-action my-four-name`

Comment: @ArunPJohny - no, but if you wrap them in another div , it is all gone .. http://jsfiddle.net/4cdak/3/

Comment: Read [Attribute Starts With Selector name^="value"](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4cdak/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not the attribute selector, it is the target element selector.

You are hiding all div elements whose `aria-describedby` attribute does not contain `four`, instead you need to fine tune the selector to target only those element you want. In your case since all the div's share the class `someclass` use it like

```
jQuery('div.someclass:not([aria-describedby*="four"])').hide()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4cdak/4/)

Comment: Thanks ! I wanted the [exact opposite](http://jsfiddle.net/4cdak/5/) . but it works now ...

Comment: can you please briefly explani to me the additional code at the top? why is it needed ? [Not working without](http://jsfiddle.net/4cdak/6/)

Comment: @ObmerkKronen your code `jQuery('div:not([aria-describedby*="four"])').hide()` says hide all `div` elements without the attribute `aria-describedby` containing `four`. Now you have a container div which does not have `aria-describedby` attribute so it  returns true for the condition so it gets hidden

Comment: @ObmerkKronen can you tell me for which one you want the explanation

Comment: i meant the code `return $(this).attr('aria-describedby')`. sorry, I just really want to learn and understand more

Comment: ok... since you give an empty div in your html markup to know which div's are hidden we need to have some content shown in the idv

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48122/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-obmerk-kronen)